# close console after VBS script executes

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a multi screen computers system. Once in a while, for a reason I don't understand, the dialog boxes are on the wrong monitor. For instance, I'll have a program running in monitor A and an OK box will open in monitor D. This is very frustrating.

I found a VBS script called "PositionDialogs.vbs" found here: https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/scripts/

```
Const SNAP_TO_MONITOR = False 'set this to True to ensure dialogs aren't placed between two monitors
Const INTERVAL = 2 'number of seconds the script waits before enumerating open windows again

Set sys = CreateObject("UltraMon.System")
Set wnd = CreateObject("UltraMon.Window")
Set wndParent = CreateObject("UltraMon.Window")

'create the two maps used to store positioned windows
Set arrAdd = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set arrLookup = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Do While True
    'enumerate all application windows
    For Each w In wnd.GetAppWindows(True)
        If w.HWndParent <> 0 Then
            wndParent.HWnd = w.HWndParent

            move = True
            If arrLookup.Exists(w.HWnd) = True Then move = False
            arrAdd.Add w.HWnd, 0

            If move = True Then
                If SNAP_TO_MONITOR = False Then
                    If w.Monitor <> wndParent.Monitor Then
                        w.Monitor = wndParent.Monitor
                        w.ApplyChanges 1 + 2 'WNDCHANGE_RESIZE_TO_FIT + WNDCHANGE_CLIP_TO_WORKSPACE
                    End If
                Else
                    Set parentMon = sys.Monitors(wndParent.Monitor - 1)
                    parentLeft = parentMon.WorkLeft
                    parentTop = parentMon.WorkTop
                    parentRight = parentLeft + parentMon.WorkWidth
                    parentBottom = parentTop + parentMon.WorkHeight

                    dlgLeft = w.Left
                    dlgTop = w.Top
                    dlgRight = dlgLeft + w.Width
                    dlgBottom = dlgTop + w.Height

                    If dlgLeft < parentLeft Then
                        w.Left = parentLeft
                    ElseIf dlgRight > parentRight Then
                        w.Left = parentRight - w.Width
                    End If
                    If dlgTop < parentTop Then
                        w.Top = parentTop
                    ElseIf dlgBottom > parentBottom Then
                        w.Top = parentBottom - w.Height
                    End If

                    w.ApplyChanges 0
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'swap maps, then clear arrAdd. this way we don't have entries for windows which no longer exist
    Set temp = arrLookup
    Set arrLookup = arrAdd
    Set arrAdd = temp
    Set temp = Nothing
    arrAdd.RemoveAll

    WScript.Sleep INTERVAL * 1000
Loop
```

that will move the dialog box to whatever monitor called it. 
I have it running on Windows startup using a batch file, and it runs as a process. My problem is that the console window that shows doesn't go away unless I click the X to close it.

The bath files looks like this:

```
wscript PositionDialogs.vbs
exit
```

I assume there is something I can add to the script to make it close after it loads itself into memory? If so, what?

Comment: Try to use `cscript` rather than `wscript`...

Comment: It runs continuously.

Comment: And type it in Start - Run dialog (Winkey + R)

Comment: That script will run continuously as @Noodles points out. There is no condition in the loop to break out of it and because the loop condition is just `True` it will continue to run and run. Somewhere in the loop you need to define a `Exit Do` or change the loop condition to at some point to exit the loop.

Comment: Description of that script from [the link](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/scripts/) - *"Positions dialog windows such as a File Open dialog on the same monitor as the parent application. **The script runs constantly in the background**, to terminate it open Task Manager, then terminate the wscript.exe process. Requires UltraMon 3.1.0 or later."*

Comment: yes I realize the script runs continuously. If I close the console window, it will continue to run as a task, until I go into task manager and kill it. I just want to close the console window automatically, not stop the script from running.

Answer (score 0):

aschipf was correct.
I made the batch file

```
start PositionDialogs.vbs
exit
```

(used START instead of WSCRIPT) and it closed as expected, while the process still ran in task manager